# How to make KMPlayer use the same audio decoder as MPC HC?

Tags: audio

I have noticed that when watching movies with either MPC HC or KMPlayer, the sound quality is slightly better with Media Player Classic Home Cinema, even after doing some tweaks.

Can anyone help me make KMPlayer use the same audio decoder as MPC HC?

Thanks in advance.